# JAXB classes missing form eclipse Enterprise edition

Tags: java, eclipse, xsd, jaxb

I need to create JAXB schema from Java class and vice-versa and i have installed the proper version of eclipse, since its stated that the EE edition has support for JAXB classes. 
However i have none of them.

When i try to create new file or even project nothing appears in the search bar:

[image]

I considered trying to download some sort of plug in for jaxb specifically, but for now im trying not to use this approach.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the java version?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam i am using JDK 1.8

Comment: How did you install this copy of Eclipse?

Comment: And what wizard are you searching for?

Comment: @nitind i downloaded the official eclipse and istalled the EE version(nothing special), and im looking through the project/file creation wizard for some jaxb related projects and schemas

Comment: JAXB is a set of APIs, not a type of application on its own.